# Como passar arquivo do drawable como parametro?

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema que deve ser simples, quero passar para outra activity, um drawable como parametro.

aqui está minha função do Onclick:

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
        Intent it = new Intent(List.this, StoryActivity.class);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable();
        it.putExtras();
        startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Por exemplo, tenho um arquivo de imagem chamado img1.jpg.

Quero que essa função passe para a outra activity esse parametro, para que assim que a segunda activity for acionada ela saiba qual arquivo mostrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de você passar o Drawable como parâmetro, você pode passar apenas o **Resource ID** dele e depois instanciar o Drawable na outra activity usando esse Resource ID. É bom saber que ao passar um objeto de uma activity para outra exige a execução de [Serialização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), o que pode ser custoso dependendo do tamanho e complexidade do objeto serializado.

O que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

**Na sua activity que enviará o drawable**

```
img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(List.this, StoryActivity.class);
        int drawableId = //R.drawable.meu_drawable_id
        it.putExtra("drawable_id", drawableId);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

**Na sua activity que receberá o drawable**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(){

    /*...*/

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int drawableId = intent.getIntExtra("drawable_id", 0); // 0 é apenas um valor default caso o drawableId não seja passado

    Drawable meuDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);

   /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Deixei assim: int drawable = //R.drawable.img1
Quando defini o putExtras do jeito que falou ele me retornou um erro dizendo: "Cannot resolve method 'putExtras(java.lang.String, int)'

Comment: Única modificação que tive que fazer foi no "it.puExtra(...);"
Ficou sem o 's' no final do metodo

Comment: @felipe218 , bem observado, eu escrevi o método errado. O correto é usar `putExtra()` e não `putExtras()`